# mysql query does not work (running two INSERTs simultaneously)

Tags: php, mysql

I have some query in my code

```
...
echo $query;
mysql_query($query) 
or die(mysql_error());
```

when I run this,output the following:

```
INSERT INTO test ( c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) 
VALUES ('xo', 'VxbcS','rzDMœSfsg', 'œsAcdiNwu','axaWMYOOj'); 
INSERT INTO test ( c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) 
VALUES ('ihTnUcBU', 'plKtJdsRT','PyJUPBx', 'f','SspBuWJiK'); 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL   server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT 
INTO test ( c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) VALUES ('ihTnUcBU', 'plKtJdsRT',' at line 3
```

if I copy the insertion query above and run it directly in phpmyadmin, it works without any problem. but it does not work when I run the php code, does any body know what seems to be wrong here? thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run just one query at time.

or use a multi-insert query

```
INSERT INTO test ( c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) 
VALUES 
('xo', 'VxbcS','rzDMœSfsg', 'œsAcdiNwu','axaWMYOOj'), 
('ihTnUcBU', 'plKtJdsRT','PyJUPBx', 'f','SspBuWJiK');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,,I need to run a big number of queries at once. is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Nick is correct, you can only run 1 query at a time with mysql_query. Have you considered using a stored procedure (routine) to achieve this? Also, have you ever looked at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?

Comment: how do I use PDO, is there any quick tutorial?

Comment: PDO is just another way to access the DB, that isnt "locked" to mysql. A quick tutorial can be found [here](http://php.tutorialref.com/pdo-mysql-connect-example.html), and some reasons for using it [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).